# how to apply babel plugin on code in js file

Tags: plugins, babeljs

I am trying to apply babel plugin on code source something like this

```
code = require('babel-core').transform(code, {
      plugins: ['some plugin']
    })
```

above code is var that contains actual code as a string, what is the right way to do above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example shows how you can transform your code according to different babel plugins.

Using babel-core **transform** method (you already doing).

[image]

Output will be transpiled code according to babel-plugin.

[image]

You can refer to this [link](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core#babeltransformcode-string-options-options-object) for more babel methods.

Hope it helps you :)